# Turn Pandas Multi-Index into column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, flatten, multi-index

I have a dataframe with 2 index levels:

```
                         value
Trial    measurement
    1              0        13
                   1         3
                   2         4
    2              0       NaN
                   1        12
    3              0        34
```

Which I want to turn into this:

```
Trial    measurement       value

    1              0        13
    1              1         3
    1              2         4
    2              0       NaN
    2              1        12
    3              0        34
```

How can I best do this?

I need this because I want to aggregate the data [as instructed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20108446/1893275), but I can't select my columns like that if they are in use as indices.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18624039/pandas-reset-index-on-series-to-remove-multiindex  You want the first suggestion. `.reset_index()`

Comment: many thanks, I actually browsed around for this a lot, but "make multiindex to column" and similar queries always got me threads which wanted to pivot their dataframes...

Comment: Always easier to find an answer when you already know it :)

Answer (score 327, accepted):

The *reset_index()* is a pandas DataFrame method that will transfer index values into the DataFrame as columns.  The default setting for the parameter is *drop=False* (which will keep the index values as columns).

All you have to do call `.reset_index()` after the name of the DataFrame:

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

Comment: For my case where I had 3 index levels inplace reset did not work.  Alternative is assigning newly resetted dataframe to a new one:  df2 = df.reset_index()

Comment: To reset only a particular level(s), use `df.reset_index(level=[...])`

Comment: Or the side-effect (probably quicker) way: `df.reset_index(inplace=True)`

Comment: `df.reset_index(names=['a', 'b'])` to provide names/alternative names to the produced columns.

Answer (score 38):

This doesn't really apply to your case but could be helpful for others (like myself 5 minutes ago) to know. If one's multindex have the same name like this:

```
                         value
Trial        Trial
    1              0        13
                   1         3
                   2         4
    2              0       NaN
                   1        12
    3              0        34
```

`df.reset_index(inplace=True)` will fail, cause the columns that are created cannot have the same names.

So then you need to rename the multindex with `df.index = df.index.set_names(['Trial', 'measurement'])` to get:

```
                           value
Trial    measurement       

    1              0        13
    1              1         3
    1              2         4
    2              0       NaN
    2              1        12
    3              0        34
```

And then `df.reset_index(inplace=True)` will work like a charm.

I encountered this problem after grouping by year and month on a datetime-column(not index) called `live_date`, which meant that both year and month were named `live_date`.

Comment: How to have your Trial values to repeat themselves? I had the same problem and it works except my values don't repeat themselves.

Answer (score 25):

There may be situations when `df.reset_index()` cannot be used (e.g., when you need the index, too). In this case, use `index.get_level_values()` to access index values directly:

```py
df['Trial'] = df.index.get_level_values(0)
df['measurement'] = df.index.get_level_values(1)
```

This will assign index values to individual columns **and** keep the index.

See the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html) for further info.

Comment: This is soooooooooo useful! It should be possible to do this using much clearer language, e.g. `df['measurement'] = df.index.values(1)`.

Answer (score 19):

As @cs95 mentioned in a comment, to drop only one level, use:

`df.reset_index(level=[...])`

This avoids having to redefine your desired index after reset.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into Karl's issue as well. I just found myself renaming the aggregated column then resetting the index.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['arms', 'success'])['success'].sum()).rename(columns={'success':'sum'})
```

[image]

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Short and simple**

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'test_col': df['test_col'].describe()})
df2 = df2.reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [Alex solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64550741/15330539) in a more generalized form. It keeps the indexes untouched and adds the index levels as new columns with its name.

```py
for i in df.index.names:
    df[i] = df.index.get_level_values(i)
```

which gives the new columns 'Trial' and 'measurement'

```
                   value Trial    measurement
Trial measurement             
    1           0     13     1              0     
                1      3     1              1     
                2      4     1              2     
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution that might be helpful in cases when not every column has multiple index levels:

```
df.columns = df.columns.map(''.join)
```