# Pandas Multiindex get values from first entry of index

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have the following multiindex dataframe:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
datastring = StringIO("""File,no,runtime,value1,value2
    A,0, 0,12,34
    A,0, 1,13,34
    A,0, 2,23,34
    A,1, 6,23,38
    A,1, 7,22,38
    B,0,17,15,35
    B,0,18,17,35
    C,0,34,23,32
    C,0,35,21,32
    """)    
df = pd.read_csv(datastring, sep=',')
df.set_index(['File','no',df.index], inplace=True)


>> df
               runtime  value1  value2
File   no               
A      0    0     0       12      34
            1     1       13      34
            2     2       23      34
       1    3     6       23      38
            4     7       22      38
B      0    5     17      15      35
            6     18      17      35
C      0    7     34      23      32
            8     35      21      32
```

What I would like to get is just the first values of every entry with a new file and a different number

```
A 0 34
A 1 38
B 0 35
C 0 32
```

The most similar questions I could find where these

[Resample pandas dataframe only knowing result measurement count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20107958/resample-pandas-dataframe-only-knowing-result-measurement-count/20108446#20108446)

[MultiIndex-based indexing in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964493/multiindex-based-indexing-in-pandas)

[Select rows in pandas MultiIndex DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53927460/select-rows-in-pandas-multiindex-dataframe)

but I was unable to construct a solution from them. The best I got was the `ix` operation, but as the values technically are still there (just not on display), the result is

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df.loc[idx[:,0],:]
```

could, for example, filter for the `0` value but would still return the entire rest of the dataframe.

Is a multiindex even the right tool for the task at hand? How to solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) by first and second level of `MultiIndex`:

```
s = df.groupby(level=[0,1])['value2'].first()
print (s)
File  no
A     0     34
      1     38
B     0     35
C     0     32
Name: value2, dtype: int64
```

If need one column `DataFrame` use one element `list`:

```
df1 = df.groupby(level=[0,1])[['value2']].first()
print (df1)
         value2
File no        
A    0       34
     1       38
B    0       35
C    0       32
```

Another idea is remove `3rd` level by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and filter by [`Index.get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df2 = df.reset_index(level=2, drop=True)
s = df2.loc[~df2.index.duplicated(), 'value2']
print (s)
File  no
A     0     34
      1     38
B     0     35
C     0     32
Name: value2, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, I would like to add another method (which I would not have found without the answere by jezrael).

```
s = df.groupby(level=[0,1])['value2'].nth(0)
```

This can be generalized to finding any, not merely the first entry

```
t = df.groupby(level=[0,1])['value1'].nth(1)
```

Note that the selection was changed from `value2` to `value1` as for the former, the results of `nth(0)` and `nth(1)` would have been identical.

Pandas documentation link: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.nth.html